# Scrapy: Is it possible scrapy with captcha?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, web-crawler

I want to scrape this [site](http://portal.cfm.org.br/index.php?option=com_medicos&nomeMedico=&ufMedico=GO&crmMedico=&municipioMedico=&tipoInscricaoMedico=&situacaoMedico=&detalheSituacaoMedico=&especialidadeMedico=&areaAtuacaoMedico=&g-recaptcha-response=03AHaCkAYFsgKBMmA1pC2BCyoUwiRmMn_I95ojy4OgnDN0dHGy12pzasxAqGPuVE7oTiFayK5e2d6vWdkkvNN-wHSXpp0dT0bpnLYX_kgIrtX4nKjDP9ot4HNwjEQilQLfjY9UH3EvIillHM-ODGLNAoKCFufPz8sONYXnFD5jcsUPoxLtsW4JOxYNQCA5gmICdJNiqz6KjvvWk3B52UVw-7GjK5idYz_pxnML7sYhM1puxNmIxALPUg1OyYKihyqS4LQDeLXvkHcdOTipau53QG0JmE9Q7KgTqkqRmEe_tdVKNe7Cx3WIodZzJ9uaV-oTXvgzIo-vDEQHeNtTcSDu9YbAdJtqEmoYIgKPku5X0cUCouHSDQD3iDV1ct09XyCfS0xGO7LKYaoCpCrxKpJzbf6r7xdL7L1qPg&pagina=4#resultado)

but it has captcha protection.

There is some way to mark the button:

"I'm not a robot" with Python Scrapy?

Comment: If you could do that, what would be the point of captchas?

Answer (score 2):

This happens when you make frequent request to a webpage. Scrapy is not a browser automation tool. It just requests a page and parses html. In your problem if you want to fill captcha programmatically you can use selenium. But that is so heavy and a burden on RAM.

The solution is to use proxy or user agent rotation . For example:-

```
user-agents=['mozilla 1/0', 'googlebot']
```

And choose random user-agent like:-

```
random_agent=random.choice(user_agent)
```

Now you use the generated user agent while requesting a page.

Scrapy also provide many middlewares for this purpose.
https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.4/topics/spider-middleware.html

List of user agents:-
https://deviceatlas.com/blog/list-of-user-agent-strings

Web crawlers uses such techniques Cheers!